# Why in Google App Engine Always 11 secs of Latency coming only for the first requests?

Tags: android, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying my `Nodejs` sample app to `Google App Engine Flexible` env and when I am using google app engine URL which is in the form `appspot.com` to hit my API, it is taking around 11 secs to send response from my `mobile data`, but other APIs are sending response in milisecs.

Also, the time delay is only happening when I am opening my android app and sending request to the server after that all requests are taking normal time, and again delay is coming when I again open the app and send request to the server.

**Edit** - I found that

> This can be a caused when your application is still booting up or warming up instances to serve the request and can be called as loading latency. To avoid such scenarios you can implement health check handler like readiness check so that your application will only receive traffic when its ready

That's why I checked in my Logs that `readiness` check is performed sometimes around `1 sec`
and sometimes around `200 ms`

[image]

Can anyone please tell me is there anything wrong in warming up my instances because I don't think cold boot time is causing this problem.

**Edit 2**

I have also tried to set `min_num_instances: 2` so that once loaded atleast my 2 instances will again not get boot up, but the thing is delay is again same.

**Edit 3**

```
runtime: nodejs
#vm: true
env: flex

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 3
```

**Edit 4**

I am noticing a strange behaviour that when I am using this app [Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en_IN) to capture traffic, then all https requests (if I am not enabling SSL Proxying) and all Http requests are executing in milisecs whereas without using this app all Http/Https requests are taking 11-16 secs of delay.

I don't know how but is there any certificate kind of issue here?

**Edit 5**

Below I have attached Network Profiler where delay is coming 15 secs

[image]

Please Help

Comment: Do you see this latency reported in the GAE request logs? Or is it just something noticed just on the app side?

Comment: @DanCornilescu No there was no latency in the Logs or in the Trace.

Comment: Sounds like it could be something on your mobile app side: initializing, registration, DNS resolution.

Comment: @DanCornilescu then why other apis are always giving resposne in milisecs?

Comment: Are the others the first to be called?

Comment: @DanCornilescu yes.

Comment: @DanCornilescu regarding this healthch eck, readiness check, cold boot time. Can you please help me to check whether the error is present at them or not? Please Help.

Comment: That should matter only if you don't have a GAE instance already running when your mobile app makes the 1st call. But if you see the delay when you restart the mobile app while the instance is already running (you can check this) then the cold boot time is not the issue. The logs you show don't indicate any suspicious delay, at least not on the GAE side.

Comment: @DanCornilescu So where can this error be, Nothing showing up :( Thanks for helping me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved now, it was happening because of network service provider which is Bharti Airtel, their DNS lookup was taking the time to resolve the hostname. After explicitly using alternative DNS like Google `8.8.8.8` the issue got completely resolved. Maybe it's a compatibility issue of Airtel with Google Cloud.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on which App Engine you are using and how you setup the scaling, there's always a loading time if you don't have a ready instance to serve a request. But if you have readiness check to ensure your instance is ready (and not cold started for the request), then there shouldn't be a problem.

Can you find a loading request or any corresponding slow request in your logs? If not, then it's likely an issue with the app. If possible, instead of calling this API on your app, do it from two apps (one is already open, one is not). So you make calls from both apps and if you notice that the one that's already open is getting a response faster than the other one, that means that's a problem with the app itself. App Engine can't determine whether or not your app is pre-opened so any difference would be client side.

=== Additional information ===

In the your logs, there's no delay at all. The request enter Google and was processed within a few milliseconds. I am sure there's something application-side. Maybe your app is constructing the request URL (first request) from some other source that results in the delay? App Engine has no knowledge of whether or not your app is opened or not or whether it's sending a first request after being opened, it cannot act differently based on it. As long as your App Engine instance is ready and available, it will treat your request the same way regardless of whether or not it's your first request after the app is opened.

Comment: I made requests from two apps, one was already open and one was not, but the thing is for both of my apps first request it took 11 secs, and after that for both latency is near around same. I do no think error is on client side, becasue I am using sample code consisting of only one request and have tried different libraries also but the error is still there, which means error must be present on App Engine side.

Comment: In that case, please provide your scaling configuration so we can take a look.

Comment: scaling configuration?

Comment: Awarding you the bounty, Still looking for an answer :(

Comment: I mean the scaling configurations as detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#services).

Comment: Do you mean app.yaml, I have added in my post, please check the updated post :)

Comment: Can you please see my edited post where i am using Packet Capture app.

Comment: To isolate the issue, please try to use [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#manual-scaling) and just have 2 or 3 instances always up for the request and see if it still results in the same delay.

Comment: No luck still facing same issues that were happening before.

Comment: But the thing is why it is working when I am using other proxy apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en_IN

Comment: I am not sure if I follow your latest edit. Could you explain a bit more? If your app engine instance is up and working, then the delay must come from some where else. If you are using manually scaled instances, there's no reason for any loading requests or anything to slow down the app. Simply go into your app engine logs and then send a request and see what the request time is on Google's end (in the logs). A screenshot of the request would help. If it's showing 50 milliseconds or something on our end, but it takes 10 seconds for your app to react, that's likely something on the app side.

Comment: On App side request logs are coming after 11 secs, that's why I don't know where these 11 secs are getting wasted.

Comment: Also Regarding last edit part, I was trying to say that when I am using any proxy app on android for example Packet Capture present in the above link, then all requests are getting executed without delay, So I don't think there is any driver issue on mobile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179849/discussion-between-ying-li-and-sudhanshu-gaur).

Comment: I have attached two tcpdump files where I can see lag for 15 secs, can you please have a look at my issuetracker

Comment: Have you checked the files?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, if your app works on wifi but not on mobile data (delay only on mobile data), that's clearly an issue outside of our control. Google network comes into play after your request goes through your mobile network, so that makes complete sense why you won't see the delay in your Google logs. We simply received your request later. Please keep in mind that on the issue tracker, we can only provide Google-side assistance and we are not seeing any latency on our end. If you need code assistance, please provide your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked I remember having to put a **warmup request handler** so that Google would know that the instance is up and running and can be used to answer calls. Keep in mind that code has to be EXACTLY under the endpoint you specify in the handler under the `yaml` file. (Wouldn't be the first time someone forgets that)

Here are the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/configuring-warmup-requests this is python specific, but you can also check other languages like Go, Java, and such in the docs.

If the problem is client dependant (each time a new clients spawns and makes a call it gets the latency) then it is most likely, either a problem with the client app itself or with initialization, registration or DNS resolution.

You could also try to reproduce the requests with CURL or similar, and see if also with those you see the mentioned delay.

Comment: He's using App Engine Flex. We don't have [warmup requests for GAE Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading#warmup_requests)

Comment: Didn't manage to read that (even if it is in the 1st line of the question), then the question is what node is doing when processing the 1st request of a user, is it creating a session or some kind of heavy work that could add the latency?

Comment: I originally though it's his app's overhead, but he preopened the app and gets the same thing. I would really need to see his app.yaml to figure it out. It "sounds like" loading request but he shouldn't need those with readiness checks keeping the instance alive.