# Android Is it possible to log each client-server connection for a single request?

Tags: android, http, interceptor

I am using `Retrofit 2` to send request to my Server, and I am facing a huge delay in my android app that's why I want to print all server-client connection logs, in the `Network layer`, `transport layer` etc.

When is the connection established and all?

Can anyone please tell me Is there any way by way I can log each and every layer request android side or it's not possible to do that.

I am currently using `HttpLoggingInterceptor` but it only shows request and response logs but not the interaction between the server and the client?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about the NetworkLayer etc. But you can use `HttpLoggingInterceptor` with retrofit to do the loggin of request sent and request from server.

Comment: I have already used `HttpLoggingInterceptor`, but it shows only request and response, not all connections between the server and the client :(

Comment: It is also possible that your Api is taking time in giving response. You can verify that using software like PostMan. This way you will be sure which end has the issue.

Comment: The response is coming in milisecs when I am using postman or even connecting my android phone to a proxy. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129452/why-in-google-app-engine-always-11-secs-of-latency-coming-only-for-the-first-req/52158357?noredirect=1#comment91515203_52158357

Comment: Okay, this is bigger then it looks like. I'll get back if I have something useful.

Comment: @siddharthjain thanks